# JS Validation Allow Space

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, space

I have regExp in JS to validate first/last names `var regExp = /^[A-Za-z]$/;`, and I want to allow space with it, how can i?

Right now its allowing a to z and A to Z chars only, i only need to allow space.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution by @ThiefMaster shows how you can add a space to your regular expression.

However, if your intent is to match a name then you can probably do better.  For example, you could say that a valid name is any one or more valid unicode letter characters (adapted from [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/plugins/)):

```
var unicodeWord = XRegExp("\\p{L}+");
unicodeWord.test("San Juan"); // true
unicodeWord.test("Русский"); // true
unicodeWord.test("日本語"); // true
unicodeWord.test("العربية"); // true
```

**[Edit]**

Note that the above expression matches any name which has one or more Unicode letter including names which include other characters (like "San Juan", "O'Connors", or "Anne-Marie").

Comment: `\p{L}` is better than `[a-zA-Z]` but doesn't match names like `O'Connors` nor `Anne-Marie`

Comment: any solution for names like that?

Comment: @iamtheladylegend : just add those chars in the class char as `[\p{L}'-]`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot validate natural names by any regular expression. So please stop doing it - it just pisses of users who have characters in their name not matchign your regex.

Anyway, `/^[A-Za-z ]$/` is the regex you are looking for.

Comment: `/^[A-Za-z0-9 ]$/` if i write like this, it will allow, 0-9 as well?

Comment: You need to add a quantifier to allow more than 1 char.

Comment: @iamtheladylegend `/^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$/` the '+' quantifier allows 1 or more character from the character class `[A-Za-z0-9 ]`